# ReactJS using in Laravel via laravel package such as php artisan preset react is a good option or not and is it good practice as per standards?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

Can anyone tell ReactJS using in Laravel is a good option or not and is it good practice as per standards?

Such as Laravel provides a way via using php artisan preset react
so like this it's a good practice to do.

Answer (score 1):

React is just a frontend library for building UI stuff. For the backend you can use any language or framework you like.

Comment: Hey Binit, I am saying that Laravel provides a way to use ReactJS via package so it is good practice to do as per standards or not ?

Comment: For that I'm not sure because I'm not well versed in PHP and Laravel.

Comment: Okay no problem
Thanks